# Rails 3 - When loading a partial how to Combine a String (comment_) with a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following:

commentable.id =3131

In the partial:

```
<%=f.text_area :content, :id=> 'comment_content_' commentable.id %>
```

I want it to make:

```
<textarea id="comment_content_3131" />
```

How do I combine the string with a variable in the partial? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just concatenate the two strings:

```
<%=f.text_area :content, :id=> ('comment_content_' + commentable.id.to_s) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you would substitute any other string. :)

```
<%= f.text_area :content, :id=> "comment_content_#{commentable.id}" %>
```